# Unable to create a view for a redshift table that has interleaved sort keys defined

Tags: sorting, view, amazon-redshift

I have a table in Redshift that has the interleaved sort keys defined. I am trying to create a view pointing to this table and it does not allow me perform select on this view because the table has interleaved sort keys defined. If I switch the sort key to default (compound) then it works fine, but given the scenario I am in, interleaved sort key style works best. What is the reason view does not work with interleaved sort key and if there's any workaround?

Thanks

PS - Created a view on the Redshift table that has interleaved sort keys defined. View creation is successful, but performing a select on the view fails.

Comment: Many questions - what is the error message? what type of view? what is the view's query?  What is the failing query? What other tables or views are referenced in the view or the query?

Comment: @BillWeiner It's a normal view created to point a table in another database.
Table 'table_A' created in schema 'source' in database1 (This table has interleaved sort keys defined on 4 columns)

Trying to create view 'view_A' in schema 'view_source' in database2. This view selects all columns as-is from Table 'A', no filters and no joins with another table. Something like this

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_source.view_A
AS SELECT * 
   FROM database1.source.table_A;

`SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: Accessing relation 'table_A' with interleaved sort keys is not supported.`

Comment: OK so separate databases.  Are these databases on different datashares?  Per the Redshift docs "Amazon Redshift doesn't support sharing tables with interleaved sort keys and views that refer to tables with interleaved sort keys".  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/considerations.html  Datashares are "associated with a specific database in your Amazon Redshift cluster".  If not datashare-ing this may a deeper level of investigation.